# Solve covariance matrix of multivariate gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution

This is a practical, and basic question. I have a multivariate Gaussian in $M$ dimensions with center $\mu$ (known, lets assume $0$) and some points $p$ where I have the value of

$$
    \ln(L)= -\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}
$$

My questions is how do I find $\Sigma$ exactly, given $\ln(L)$ and $\mathbf{x}$ values? I.e. which quantities go into a linear matrix equation solver $Ax=b$.

In particular, I am confused how to make a system of linear equations built from this one matrix multiplication.

Comment: The points are not drawn from the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_of_covariance_matrices) on estimation of covariance matrices is relevant.

If $\Sigma$ is an $M\times M$ variance of a $M$-dimensional Gaussian, then I think you'll get a non-unique answer if the sample size $n$ is less than $M$.  The likelihood would be
$$
\log L(\Sigma) \propto -\frac n2\log\det\Sigma - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^T \Sigma^{-1} x_i. 
$$
In each term in this sum $x_i$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^{M\times 1}$.  The value of the constant of proportionality (dismissively alluded to by "$\propto$") is irrelevant beyond the fact that it's positive.

You omitted the logarithm of the determinant and all mention of the sample size.

To me the idea (explained in detail in the linked Wikipedia article) that it's useful to regard a scalar as the trace of a $1\times1$ matrix was somewhat startling.  I learned that in a course taught by Morris L. Eaton.

What you end up with --- the value of $\Sigma$ that maximizes $L$ --- is the maximum-likelihood estimator $\widehat\Sigma$ of $\Sigma$.  It is a (matrix-valued) random variable in its own right because it depends on $x_i$.  It would have a Wishart distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.  It is more usualy to treat $\mu$ as unknown and substitute its maximum-likelihood esimator for it, and since that is itself a random variable, that changes the distribution of $\widehat\Sigma$ so that it's a Wishart distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, and that's what you'll find in most of the literature on this and in particular in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: This assumes the points are drawn from the distribution. Mine are not, but I have the $\ln L$ values.

Comment: Your question is not altogether clear.  You have $-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}$.  What is $\mathbf{x}$?  Is it a single $M\times1$ column vector?  If so, then knowing the value of $\log L$ is certainly not enough information.  Or might it be an $M\times n$ matrix, so that in effect you have $n$ points in $M$-space?  If so, then $-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and then so is $\log L$.  Or might it be a sum of terms each looking like $-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: . . . . . or might it be that you know the value of $-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^{\rm T}\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}\mathbf{x}$ for each of $n$ vectors $\mathbf{x}$ separately (and these are known vectors)?  If so, you'd have $n$ different scalar values of $\log L$.  In that last situation you could find $\Sigma$ if at least $M$ of the $n$ vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: x is a single column vector, for one $log L$ as in the equation. I have many such points with their $log L$. Precisely the last situation.

Comment: I think we might need $\mathbf{x}_i^T\Sigma\mathbf{x}_j$ for $i\ne j$, and a sufficiently large number of such instances.  Are the $\mathbf{x}$ values to the right and left of $\Sigma$ in every case the same?

Comment: Yes, because that's how the normal distribution works. But look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465306/system-of-matrix-equations/465323 , I asked about just the linalg part, i.e. finding the matrix, there. Not quite sure yet how to implement it though.

Comment: That question is nearly identical to this one.