# system of matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the equation $ \mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x} = b $, where $b$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{x}$ a vector of size $M$, and A a matrix of size $M\times M$. $b$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are given.

How many such equations do I need to find the (common) $A$, and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can only find the symmetric part of $A$, since $x^TAx=x^TA^Tx$.

So let us say that $A$ is already symmetric. A symmetric matrix has $\frac12M(M+1)$ degrees of freedom, so you need at least that many equations.

Now let $e_j$ be the $j$th natural basis vector, and note that $e_j^TAe_j=a_{jj}$, while $(e_j+e_k)^TA(e_j+e_k)=a_{jj}+2a_{jk}+a_{kk}$. I have now named $\frac12M(M+1)$ vektors (all $e_j$, and all $e_j+e_k$ with $j<k$) sufficient to let you determine $A$ from the given equations.

PS. You may wonder what it takes for an arbitrary set of $\frac12M(M+1)$ vektors $x$ to be sufficient. One answer comes from noting that $x^TAx=\operatorname{tr}(xx^TA)$, and noting that $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(B^TA)$ is an inner product on the space of symmetric matrices, the answer is that all the matrices $xx^T$ must be linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am thinking about it.

Comment: I think I get it. The linear equation system would be
$\sum_j \sum_i x_i^k a_{ij} x_j^k - L^k = 0$ and
$a_{ij} - a_{ji} = 0$, 
with M/2 * (M + 1) equations (k).

Comment: I use $X_k = (x_{k,i,i}, x_{k,i,j>i})$ (meaning I flatten the matrix into a vector, diagonal first, then rest) and $A = (a_{i,i}, a_{i,j>i})$, solving $X A = L_k$. Thanks!